# How to inject the mock of an object which is declared as private static in the class under test in java?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have a class ManageUser as below:

```
public class ManageUser {
private static UserBO gUserBO = new UserBO();

 public String method1() {

    gUserBO.callSomeFunction();

    gUserBO.callSomeOtherFunction();

  }
}
```

Now, I have a test class where I want to test method1() and since the methods callSomeFunction() and callSomeOtherFunction() end up making database calls I want to mock the calls to those methods. I am unable to do that by using mock since the object in ManageUser is static. How do I proceed? I am new to Junit and Mockito and can't seem to find relevant answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Power Mockito:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ManageUser.class})
public class ClassInTest {

    @Test
    public void testStatic() {
       ManageUser mUser = new ManageUser();
       Field field = PowerMockito.field(ManageUser.class, "gUserBO");
       field.set(ManageUser.class, mock(UserBO.class));
       ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You are "unable to do that by using mock" because your class is badly designed. As a workaround, you could use [PowerMock](https://github.com/powermock/powermock) (as @S.K. suggested) to mock the static field but that will only suppress the real problem of your class.

Better take the chance and improve the code for better testability and evolvability:

Step 1: Create an interface for your class `UserBO` and let it implement it.

```
public interface UserService {
    void callSomeFunction();
    void callSomeOtherFunction();
}

public class UserBO implements UserService { ... }
```

Step 2: Change your class `ManageUser` to get any implementation of `UserService` through a constructor.

```
public class ManageUser {
    private final UserService userService;

    public ManageUser(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    public String method1() {
        userService.callSomeFunction();
        userService.callSomeOtherFunction();
    }
}
```

Step 3: Change the calling side of your class `ManageUser` to provide a `UserService`.

So instead of

```
ManageUser manager = new ManageUser();
```

use

```
ManageUser manager = new ManageUser(new UserBO());
```

Step 4: Now you can easily mock a `UserService` in your test and construct a `ManageUser` with the mock.

---

This design also enables DI frameworks (e.g. Spring) to *inject* (or *autowire*) the components.